# how do I fix riverpod_lint error message 'If a provider depends on providers which specify "dependencies"...'

Tags: riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation, riverpod-lint

##### set up

1. create a new project
2. add the dependencies visible under `additional information`
3. add the files below

- foos.dart

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'foos.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class Foos extends _$Foos {
  @override
  List<String> build() => <String>[];

  Future<void> initialize() => Future.sync(
        () => state = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 'foo'],
      );
}
```

- bars.dart

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

import 'foos.dart';

part 'bars.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true, dependencies: [Foos])
class Bars extends _$Bars {
  @override
  List<String> build() => <String>[];

  Future<void> initialize() =>
      Future.sync(() => [for (final _ in ref.read(foosProvider)) 'bar']);
}
```

##### description

in `Bars`' riverpod annotation `dependencies`
`@Riverpod(keepAlive: true, dependencies: [Foos])`

Foos shows the error below

```
If a provider depends on providers which specify "dependencies", they should themselves specify "dependencies" and include all the scoped providers. dart(provider_dependencies)
```

##### question

***can someone help me understand the meaning of this error***
and how do I solve it?

##### additional information

- pubspec.yaml

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.0
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  custom_lint: ^0.3.2
  riverpod_lint: ^1.1.5
  riverpod_generator: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

- analysis_options.yaml

```yaml
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

analyzer:
  exclude:
    - "**/*.g.dart"
  plugins:
    - custom_lint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the lint's explanation and fixes [here](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_lint#provider_dependencies-riverpod_generator-only).

TL;DR: your `Bars` does not depend on `Foos`. You can see that there's no `ref.watch(foosProvider)` in its `build` method. Thus, the lint is triggered as `dependencies` shouldn't include `Foos`.

Instead, if your `initialize` method was meant to be used on `build`, you should put its contents in there, specify the dependency through `ref.watch` and add it to `dependencies` in the annotation, like so:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true, dependencies: [foos])
class Bards extends _$Bards {
  @override
  List<String> build() {
    final foos = ref.watch(foosProvider);
    return [/*... use foos as you do in `initialize`*/];
  }
}
```